# Windows Store Apps: The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match

Tags: ssl, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

in my windows 8.1 application, when I call a web service, I get the following exception:

> The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match

The code I use:

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(filter);


HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("[Service_URL]",UriKind.Absolute));
IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream=(IRandomAccessStream)await msg.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync();
```

I'm using the HttpBaseProtocolFilter to bypass the errors that could be with the server's certificate, but it seems that it does not overcome the above exception.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Instead of bypassing certificate verification, have you considered using SSL/TLS properly and making your application check both the certificate's validity and the fact its hostname matches what the application is trying to connect to?

Comment: I know that this is the right way to do it, but the current situation is just for testing purposes, besides that I don't have an access to the server, so I'm just seeking a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(
    ChainValidationResult.Untrusted |
    ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
```

For more certificate ooptions take a look at [ChainValitadionResult enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.chainvalidationresult.aspx)