# C#/UWP : How to manage certificate errors with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, ssl, uwp, certificate, httpclient

I've developed an **UWP app** for a **client**, which uses **WebServices that are hosted in its domain**.

- Until now, the URL WebServices were related to a **test server** that don't use SSL
- But now, the WebServices URL are related to the **prod server** that use **SSL**

As I'm a subcontractor, I don't have an AD account, and I need to use the VPN to access to the client's WebServices.

I didn't get any problem to access to the test server, but it's no longer the case with the prod server.

When I try to access to access to the URL through a navigator, I get a security warning message (**DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA**), but I can "force" the navigation to the URL.

But when I call the WebService from the app with `HttpCLient`, I also get an error (`HttpRequestException`) and I don't see how I could fix it.

Here are the details of the exception:

> HResult = -2147012851
>
> InnerException =
>   {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072F0D): Can't find text related to the error code. The certificate authority is invalid or is incorrect at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  ...
>
> Message = "An error occurred while sending the request."
>
> Source = "System.Net.Http"

I've already tried to install handly the certificates on my computer, but this doesn't fix the issue...

***Is there another approach?***

**Edit: add "user" certificate**

The client sent me the **"user" certificate** and I installed it on my computer in **"User\Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store"**: there is no longer problem from the navigator. However, in the app, the problem is still present.

***Is it normal? Do I need to "attach" the certificate to the app? This is not really usefull, as the client's users don't need this problem: it's only me as I'm a subcontractor using the VPN...***

**Edit: add "computer" certificate**

Finally the client sent me the **"computer" certificate** and I installed it on my computer in **"Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store"**: this time I could use the app without problem.

***It's good to know that the UWP app and the navigators don't use the same certificate.***

Comment: You may want to look at this tho : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822640/how-to-ignor-self-signed-certificates-with-system-net-http-httpclient-in-univers also, corrected your error message to the english version  since most peoples here don't speak french :)

Comment: Hi @xoxel you're right, thanks for the correction ;-) But in the URL you suggested me, the only way taht seems to work is to add the certificate to the app. This would have sense for my case, as I use the VPN to access client's server, but the client's users don't have the same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed by installing the **"user"** and **"computer" certificates** that has been sent by the client.